# Teraterm with trojan?

Tags: trojan

I have a program called Teraterm that have some little applications like keycode.exe which it is supposed to configure the keyboard to my liking but Microsoft Security Essentials detect it as a Trojan.

It's really a Trojan or not?

Comment: This question shows lack of research effort. What have you done so far?

Comment: upload the file to https://www.virustotal.com/

Comment: @CharlieRB I google it and give me 4 results that are no related to this. https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=teraterm+keycode+trojan&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=_ZozV6AKg7DABILeh-gO#q=teraterm+keycode+%2Btrojan

Comment: Where did you obtain Tera Term? Where is this `keycode.exe` located? What exactly does Security Essentials report?

Comment: @DanielB I don't remember, because I have 2 desktop PC and one notebook and I download the program in different moments for each one. Only on my PC at work is marked as Trojan:Win32/Varpes.M!cl anyway; 
I do not remember downloading the program from the OSDN site.

Answer (score 2):

Likewise, I witnessed Windows Defender report a trojan in TeraTerm 4.91 available [here](https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/index.html.en).  I believe that download of TeraTerm is safe and that the trojan detected was a false positive based on the following:

- [This site](http://tera-term.en.lo4d.com/virus-malware-tests) has scanned it using many anti virus packages and deemed it safe.
- There is a [bug filed](https://en.osdn.jp/ticket/browse.php?group_id=1412&tid=36452) that shows a known false positive when using Windows Defender (which replaces Microsoft Security Essentials on Windows 8 and greater).
- I just scanned the file using Kaspersky Anti-Virus, and it declared it contains no viruses.

It looks like Windows Defender (and likely Microsoft Security Essentials as well) doesn’t show a virus with version 4.90, if you would like to use that instead.

Comment: Without knowing which Teraterm the OP downloaded and from exactly where we cannot tell whether it is safe or not. There are many cracked versions of popular programs that contain malware....

Comment: I should have been more explicit about which Teraterm we are talking about.  I updated the answer.

Comment: FYI, the download of TeraTerm that I refer to in my answer and the one in the first bullet point have a matching MD5 filehash (ca9e6fa2136ed23a2af331a6b0c5a6d3).

Comment: Your answer may be more complete, but we still don't know where the OP got his copy from ...

Comment: True. Since we both saw a Trojan by reported by Microsoft Security software, my best guess was that the OP had the version I had, from the same source.  My hope is that my answer will help the OP and others.

Answer (score -1):

Tera Term (tera-term.exe or Tera Term Pro.exe) is a exe file associated with guide to hacking software security 2002 by Silver Star Publishing. It can be classified as a potentially unwanted program that utilizes the install Core download manager bundled with additional offers for various ad-supported extensions, toolbars and utilities. Here is a heardProtect online-scan report of TeraTerm.exe: http://www.herdprotect.com/tera-term.exe-5334b77726ba7f837f22a40060731da5b72f60d2.aspx

Comment: The application is Teraterm is a communication tool, and since Windows 7 have no longer Hyperterminal I use Teraterm instead.

Comment: Although you may be correct, can you offer some source for your answer?

Comment: @CharlieRB, Few years back, I installed this TeraTerm.exe on my Windows 7 desktop and I experienced large number of annoying pop-up ads on my Windows 7 machine. I added a link to HerdProtect scan result. It says "It uses the InstallCore download manager to install additional potentially unwanted software which may include extensions such as DealPly and various toolbars."

Comment: I think you’re confusing something. [Tera Term](https://en.osdn.jp/projects/ttssh2/) is Open Source Software and not related to UpdateStar GmbH in any way.

Comment: @DanielB, if the OP was talking about this Open Source software then I'm entirely wrong.